# How to log into Facebook using alternative accounts (Google, OpenID)

Tags: google-account, login, openid, facebook-account

Everybody has a Google account. Yet, I see no way to use it to enter the Facebook. Others say that I must check "Linked Accounts" in https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fsettings%3Fref%3Dmb but I see nothing more but

[image]

there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Shahar Sounds like an answer

Comment: I have done some research and for now I can definitely conclude that it's gone. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently **not possible**. The only way to Log in to Facebook is to use and sign up for a **Facebook Account**,

Answer (score 2):

Seems like facebook pulled out [linked accounts quite some time back](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=492258394158031).